# Windows 7 XP Mode and Visual Studio 2003

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2003

So with Windows 7's XP Mode, will this allow developers to run Visual Studio 2003 on Windows 7 without hacks?

Thanks all!
-Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, most certainly. But not "on Windows 7", rather on a virtual machine running Windows XP hosted on Windows 7.